# "Found an invalid color" when using 9 patch image for splash screen

Tags: android, nine-patch

I have a terrible problem which I can't rid of. I've got a logo in `svg` format from my designer. Now, I am using [this](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html#&sourceDensity=320&name=example) generator to produce `9 patch images` for the splash screen. In the end, I've got this error `java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details`. I have no idea where I can find these logs neither.

**What I tried:**

- convert source image to `png` first and use this in the generator but the effect was the same.
- set flag `android.enableAapt2=false` in `gradle.properties` but the error still appeared.

What can produce such error? Why my 9 patch image is corrupted?

Comment: `check logs for details`: can you do that and post what it says?

Comment: Forgot to ask where can I look for this details. Can't find them :(

Comment: It means that you used a bad color scheme in your png. Nothing to do with gradle. But we can't help any further, without seeing your image.

Comment: @KlingKlang what does it mean that I used a bad color scheme? I didn't do that image, that was my designer. What should I tell him?

Comment: You should tell him to learn how to make a 9 path out of a png. There's a great tutorial from radleymarx (or something similar... radlymax?) which covers the matter thoroughly.